# Saving sensitive images in database or in web-directory?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, security

I'm developing an online photo proof system for clients where the client is given a password and has to log in to see their albums. Some of the images may be sensitive/naked photos, which should not be available to other people.
But if a hacker was very clever he/she could just type in the URL. But then again he would have to know every name of the images and the exact folder-structure... The server is set up so that you have to know the exact url. You don't have permission to see folder-structure /file-trees. I can't override the .htaccess file.

Is this a security risk that should make me store images in a mySQL database instead of saving the files to a directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what makes you think that putting it in the db would be any safer than in the document root? `example.com/seekrit/nekkid.jpg` is no different than `example.com?image.jpg?id=42`. if you don't want something served up, then don't put it into publicly accessible areas. At least with a script you can have code checking access rights **BEFORE** serving the image.

Comment: As I see it there's no need to put the images in the URL as you show it. The website could load every photo which macthes the user in session...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a long random string and save it corresponding to user.Then it will be hard to brute force and limit frontend access limited to user by checking the credentials

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like the idea. However, I would like to password protect the albums only. In that way the client wouldn't have to log in with an account. I could still use the concept of this idea though.

Comment: so password protect them and use user credentials for access.regarding direct access keep in mind random lengthy string and store it in database attached to that person's information.I had implemented it in one of my websites i sold and it works great

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put flags in the db for ever img id, i.e. 1 for public 2 for adult, so if the user, when uploads, checks it's adult content, you insert a flag "2" in the DB. So, afterwards, make a check if the requested image has flag 1, and if false, then go to check if the $_SESSION is populated with the user owner's one, if it's foreigners sessions - don't show the content.